# Button doesnt get shown once placed higher than 200 in the y axis

Tags: python, tkinter

I would love a pointer on how to fix this bug in my code. It occurs when the button widget is placed 200 or higher in the y axis. What happens is when the button is placed it is not viewed on screen. I think its something to do with the OSU! enlarged title screen because the button cannot be placed lower than that. Please run the code and when u hit start a new screen should be shown with a button (thats how it should be) but theres a chance that wont occur so rerun the code till it appears. when the button is placed a new button will be randomly placed aswell.

I really dont know why buttons placed lower than the title doesnt show..
It would mean alot if u took ur time and helped me wit this bug

thanks for your time,
samurai

Heres the code

```
from tkinter import *
import random

global counter
counter = -1

global color_counter
color_counter = -1

win = Tk()

Titlescreen = Frame(win)
Gamescreen = Frame(win)
Deathscreen = Frame(win)

# Page 1

H1 = Label(Titlescreen, text="Osu!", font=('Helvatical bold',100))
H1.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn1 = Button(Titlescreen, text='Start', command=lambda:Gamescreen.tkraise())
btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)

#Page 2

class rectangle():
   def __init__(self, location, number, row, column, color):
       self.location = location
       self.number = number
       self.row = row
       self.column = column
       self.color = color



 #write under here the parameters for rectangle


 numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

 x= list(range(20, 380))


 y= list(range(20, 380)) 

 colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow','purple','orange','pink']

 


 def click():
     circle_button.grid_forget()
     circle()


 global circle
 def circle():
     global counter
     global color_counter
     counter += 1
     if counter == 9:
         counter = 0
         color_counter += 1

     user = rectangle(Gamescreen, numbers[counter], random.choice(x), random.choice(y), 
     colors[color_counter])
     print(random.choice(x))
     print(random.choice(y))
     global circle_button
     circle_button = Button(user.location,text=user.number, bg=user.color, command=click)


     circle_button.place(x=random.choice(x),y=random.choice(y), anchor = CENTER)
  circle()


  #Page 3

  Lb1 = Label(Deathscreen, text='GAME OVER', font=('Helvatical bold',50))
  Lb1.grid(row=0,column=1)

  btn3 = Button(Deathscreen, text='Retry', command=lambda:Gamescreen.tkraise())
  btn3.grid(row=1, column=1)

  btn4 = Button(Deathscreen, text='Exit', command=lambda:Titlescreen.tkraise())
  btn4.grid(row=2, column=1)

  Titlescreen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
  Gamescreen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
  Deathscreen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


  Titlescreen.tkraise()
  win.geometry('400x400')
  win.title('Control panel')
  win.resizable(False, False)


  win.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you set those frames to different colors, then you will find out why.

Comment: ah i  seee thanksss.. how can i make the frame the same geometry as the window?

Answer (score 0):

It is because those frames does not occupy all the space of the window.  You need to allocate all the available space to row 0 column 0:

```py
...
# allocate all available space to row 0 column 0 
win.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
win.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
...
```